# How can I fill week entries in my dataframe when I don't have rows for this week?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, week-number

I created the following data set to explain my question:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-11-01', periods=30, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] }) 

df3=df.drop([3,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
```

As can be seen in the code, I have withdrawn some data (more specifically one week). Then I want to group my data by weeks and sum the variable `Val`:

```
aux3=df3.groupby(df3['Date'].dt.week).sum()
```

And this was the output I got. As you can see in week 46, it has no value; therefore, it cannot add anything. How can I fill this week with values, such as at least zero?

```
      Val
Date     
44      0
45      6
47      7
48      0
49      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reindex with a range:

```
aux3.reindex(range(aux3.index.min(), aux3.index.max()+1), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
      Val
week     
44      0
45      6
46      0
47      7
48      0
49      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, it is an easy and fast way to solve it.